# Group items if trailed by string

Tags: python, iterable

I have `i` and need `o`.

```
i = ["file1", "file2", "join", "file3", "file4", "join", "file5", "file6"]


o = [["file1", "file2", "join"], ["file3", "file4", "join"], "file5", "file6"]
```

I tried so many hours and attempts that I can't reasonably show what I tried so far. `while`, `pop`, `index` etc come to my mind. Please bear with me, if I now only put these plain lines in order to ask for your precious help.

Comment: Is the condition to group consecutive items together until the last character of a string is not numerical? Or is it until you find the word "join"? Or a 4-character string? Or a word that doesn't start with "file"? Or something else? And are "file5" and "file6" just appended to the output because you didn't hit upon the condition to group them together into a sublist?

Comment: What did you try *so many hours* ? What do you need to do? Share the expected output?

Comment: Share the attempt you were convinced would work the most, explain what you expected and what happened instead and people will be able to explain why it didn't work and how to improve on it. Surely one of the ideas you had in many hours will have felt close?

Comment: actually `split_after` is **not** giving the expected output

Comment: @mozway Indeed. The ungrouped items (file5 and file6) should **not** be in a list. However I can easily post another question based on your suggestion.

Comment: @jjk up to you, depends if you need it ;) this would be a variation on `split_after`